# How to distinguish a '<li>' (no classes/id) from a '<li class="hasClass">'?

Tags: javascript, css, quill

I'm working with an ordered list and top-level `<li>`'s have no class. However, any `<li>`'s indented have a class of `.ql-indent-[indent-level]` with `indent-level` beginning at 1 and increasing by 1.

If the DOM looked like the following for example:

```
<ol>
  <li>This is a top-level list item</li>
  <li>This is another top-level list item</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-1">this list item has a class</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-1">this list item has a class</li>
</ol>
```

then the result would be like this (ignore the numbering):

1. This is a top-level list item
2. This is another top-level list item

   1. this list item has a class
   2. this list item has a class

**How could I distinguish between these two different types of list items (the ones with no class and one's with)?** Ultimately, I need to change the margin of the `<li>`'s however when I do the following, the classless `<li>` code is applied to the `.ql-indent-[indent-level]` elements as well. If JavaScript is needed, then the solution must be in vanilla JS, not jQuery.

```
.ql-editor li:nth-child(n+100):before { // should only work on classless <li>'s
  margin-right: 0.9em;
}

.ql-editor li:nth-child(n+1000):before { // should only work on classless <li>'s
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.ql-editor li.ql-indent-1:nth-child(n+703):before { // should only work on the .ql-indent-# <li>'s
  margin-right: 0.9em;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `:not()` `pseudo-class` **e.g:** `.ql-editor li:not(.ql-indent-1)` - **:not() CSS | MDN** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot

Comment: You are doing indenting wrong. The structure should be `ol>li>ul>li`.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: What about `.ql-indent-2`?

Comment: @dfsq: That's just how [quill](https://quilljs.com/) does it.

Comment: @Cerberus `.ql-editor li:not([class*="ql-indent-"])`

Comment: Random side node, if you're having more than 1000 list items inside a single `<ul>` there's something wrong with your UI and UX.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: that worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I had you covered, from the get-go ;) Glad you came right

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `[class]` [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
li           { background: lightgray; } /* Default li style */
li.no-indent { background: lightblue; } /* Specific li style */
li.ql-indent-1 { margin-left: 20px; }   /* Specific indent li style */
li.ql-indent-2 { margin-left: 40px; }

li[class*="ql-indent-"] {               /* All "indent" list items style */
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>This is a top-level list item</li>
  <li class="no-indent">This is another top-level list item with a class, but no indent</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-1">this list item has a class</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-2">this list item has a class</li>
</ol>
```

This will select *all* `<li>` elements that have a `class` attribute, that contains `ql-indent-`.

`li[class]` would select all `li` elements that *have* an `class` attribute.
The `*="ql-indent-"` part says:
Only select those where the attribute's value *contains* (`*="....."`) `ql-indent-`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: The OP wants to differentiate `.ql-indent-` elements from those that don't have `.ql-indent-`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: @Cerbus is correct, I needed to differentiate between the `<li>` without a class and those with a class. You're right that I needed to use the `[class]` attribute, but I needed to use that along with the `:not()` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly this one works:

```css
li {
  color:red;
}
li:not([class]){
  color:green;
}
li.ql-indent-1 {
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>This is a top-level list item</li>
  <li>This is another top-level list item</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-1">this list item has a class</li>
  <li class="ql-indent-2">this list item has a class</li>
</ol>
```

But of course the whole `class` attribute should be missing.

Comment: What if one of the `li` elements get a css class from something else? Some other library that sets hover states on them, for example? _only_ selecting `[class]` is rather fragile.

Comment: Frankly, given the actual *question* title, this answer would be considered more specific.